# Integrating MinGw compiler into Dev C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, gcc

The compiler that came with Dev C++ seems to be not perhaps updated or is old and it does not seem to support some code structures(e.g. you can't define an integer variable inside a for statement)[image],
So I wanted to use the MinGW GCC compiler for Dev C++, after downloading it, I just browsed to MinGW folder:

[image]

Though, codes have been compiling as expected so far, the dropdown as you can see has shortened out.
Was this the correct way of configuring the MinGW GCC 5.3.0 for Dev C++?

Comment: You are right that Dev-C++ is really old; my advice would be to switch to a more modern IDE personally

Comment: Why not simply download Codeblocks instead? From what I remember, the Dev C++ debugger was quite horrible.

Comment: @Lundin, sometimes after I've compiled the code once in codeblocks and make edits and try to recompile the code, it won't budge. The whole options are greyed out, worse is when I've got to restart it, takes a long time

Comment: @GovindParmar, I've tried codeblocks, but for the problem in the comment above, I was trying to find a better IDE.

Comment: @lind Sounds like a corrupt installation or some other PC issue. Also note that anti-virus programs tend to hate programmers.

Answer (score 0):

I am personally using code::blocks and it works great. I recommend you to download cod::blocks from [here](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26). I would recommend you to download the mingw-setup so that you don't have to set up the compiler and if you want to use C99 enable the -std=c99 flag from compiler settings.

For the problem you mentioned in the comment of your question, you must be running your program in the background so the options are grayed out. Check for background processes.

Comment: I did download code::blocks with the mingw setup, but stackexchangers here said that the compiler that came with it was outdated.

Comment: If you are a school or college student and even for participating in coding competitions the compiler that comes with code::blocks is enough.

Comment: why can't we even set a new compiler? I mean it's the same just the update

Comment: As per your question you have successfully integrated the compiler, but the drop-down menu has shortened out because you have changed the compiler binaries folder.